# Datagridview and two combobox (related)

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox, selectedindexchanged

i have one Datagridview and two combobox (related) When I click on dataGridView1_CellMouseClick cmbSehir.Text changes as I want. but cmbilce.Text does not change as I want!. Where do i make mistakes. I hope I made myself clear. Thanks for helping.

```
private void frmMusteriEkle_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        GetSehir();
        GetDatagridview();
    }
 private void GetSehir() {
        db.connect();
        db.SqlQuery("select * from iller");
        DataTable dt = db.GeTDataTable();
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["id"] = 0;
        dr["sehir"] = "Seçiniz:";
        dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);
        cmbSehir.DataSource = dt;
        cmbSehir.ValueMember = "id";
        cmbSehir.DisplayMember = "sehir";
        db.disconnect();
    }

private void cmbSehir_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        if (cmbSehir.SelectedIndex != 0)
            {
            db.connect();
            db.SqlQuery("select * from ilceler where il_id = ?");
            db.command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p", cmbSehir.SelectedValue);
            DataTable dt = db.GeTDataTable();
            cmbilce.DataSource = dt;
            cmbilce.ValueMember = "id";
            cmbilce.DisplayMember = "ilceler";
            db.disconnect();
            }
        else
            {
            cmbilce.DataSource = null;
            }
        }
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
        cmbSehir.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        cmbilce.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: While cmbSehir is instantiated on the loading of the form MusteriEkle, cmbilce only goes through a similar process when cmbSehir has been changed. Is cmbilce properly formatted and set to receive an update to its `.Text` value?

Comment: I did what I wanted. i call cmbilce on dataGridView1_CellMouseClick event. thx for answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing what `GetDatagridview` method does, I will assume from the lines…

```
cmbSehir.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
cmbilce.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
```

that these combo boxes are related to the data contained in columns 4 and 5. If the combo boxes have the same data source as the `DataGridView` then it is possible to bind all three controls to the same `DataSource`. After binding all three components to the same data source, clicking on a cell in the grid will automatically change the combo boxes and vice versa… changing a combo box will change the selection in the grid. There is no need to wire up the `CellMouseClick` or `SelectionChanged` events to keep the controls in sync.

Another consideration is the `cmbSehir_SelectionChangeCommitted` method that fires every time the user changes the selection in the `cmbSehir` combo box. In this method, the code queries the data base and sets the combo boxes data source. This is fine, however, are you sure you want to query the database and refill the combo box EVERY time the user changes this selection? I am guessing one query would be sufficient, until new data is added, removed or changed.

The code below sets the `DataSource` for the combo boxes to the same data source of the `DataGridView` using different `ValueMembers`.

```
DataTable AllData;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  AllData = GetDT();
  dataGridView1.DataSource = AllData;
  comboBox1.DataSource = AllData;
  comboBox2.DataSource = AllData;
  comboBox1.ValueMember = "sehir";
  comboBox2.ValueMember = "ilceler";
}
```

Comment: I did what I wanted. i call cmbilce on dataGridView1_CellMouseClick event. thx for answer.